# Sorting Array of Struct Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, qsort

I am trying to sort array of structs using `qsort()` but frustratingly, it's not working. I have read the manpage for `qsort()` and I think I have the comparator function that syntactically looks okay, but when I print the "sorted" array after calling `qsort()`, nothing is sorted in my array.

The code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SZ 5

typedef struct SingleChar
{
    unsigned char Character;
    unsigned int Weight;
} *SingleCharPtr;

int CompareWeights(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const SingleCharPtr p1 = (SingleCharPtr)a;
    const SingleCharPtr p2 = (SingleCharPtr)b;

    // printf("Weight1: %u\tWeight2: %u\n", p1->Weight, p2->Weight);
    // return (p1->Weight - p2->Weight);

    if (p1->Weight < p2->Weight)
        return -1;
    else if (p1->Weight > p2->Weight)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}


SingleCharPtr MakeChar(unsigned char c, unsigned int w)
{
    SingleCharPtr scptr = malloc(sizeof(struct SingleChar));

    if (!scptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[Error] Out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    scptr->Character = c;
    scptr->Weight = w;

    return scptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    SingleCharPtr *chars = malloc(ARRAY_SZ * sizeof(SingleCharPtr));

    chars[0] = MakeChar('B', 3);
    chars[1] = MakeChar('E', 7);
    chars[2] = MakeChar('A', 4);
    chars[3] = MakeChar('D', 6);
    chars[4] = MakeChar('C', 2);

    qsort(chars, ARRAY_SZ, sizeof(SingleCharPtr), &CompareWeights);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SZ; i++)
    {
        printf("Character: %c\tWeight: %u\n", chars[i]->Character, chars[i]->Weight);
        free(chars[i]);
    }

    free(chars);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, in the comparator function (`CompareWeights()`), I found out that when I print the weight of the structs pointed by `SingleCharPtr`, I get 0s for all of them.

Any pointer to right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post links to or screenshots of the code. Paste it here and format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem: `qsort()` passes in **pointers** to the elements to be compared to the comparator function, and not the elements themselves. So, the arguments to your `CompareWeights()` function are actually `const SingleCharPtr *`, disguised as `const void *`. What you should do in that function is:

```
const SingleCharPtr p1 = *(const SingleCharPtr *)a;
```

etc.

---

Sidenotes:

I. If your assumption had been valid, then you wouldn't have needed the cast:

```
const SingleCharPtr p1 = a;
```

is preferred over

```
const SingleCharPtr p1 = (SingleCharPtr)a;
```

because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

II. The comparison function need not return `-1`, `0` or `1`. It should return an integer less than 0, 0 or greater than 0. Thus, all the huge `if` in `CompareWeight()` is completely superfluous, write

```
return p1->Weight - p2->Weight;
```

instead.

III. `SingleCharPtr *chars = malloc(ARRAY_SZ * sizeof(SingleCharPtr));` - Why? You only use the `chars` array locally in the `main()` function, you don't need dynamic allocation for that. Why not write

```
SingleCharPtr chars[ARRAY_SZ];
```

instead?

Comment: III. This is a test program to run a bigger program I am creating. That's why I wanted to test the `*chars` pointer locally. Thanks for your answer and feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the example in e.g. [this manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort), you will see that the when `qsort` is passed an array of pointer (just like you have) then the arguments to the sorting function are actually pointers to pointers. This is because `qsort` passes pointers to the elements, not the elements themselves.

To accomodate for that, change accordingly:

```
int CompareWeights(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const SingleCharPtr p1 = *(SingleCharPtr*)a;
    const SingleCharPtr p2 = *(SingleCharPtr*)b;

    return (p1->Weight - p2->Weight);
}
```